# Difference between var private(set) and let?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I use an internal library for init objects. This library accepts only var attributes, but I don't want to change var attributes after init. This task is done by declaring attributes as let, but I can`t do that.

As a solution a use private(set) and it works very well.

But, I want to know, is there any difference between **var private(set)** and **let**?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "init objects" mean? What does "This library accepts only var attributes" mean? Please provide examples & any relevant error messages.

Comment: is a simple context. this is not the point. and tnx for your feedback :).

Comment: *"I don't know if this is a good solution."* can not be replied to if you don't provide more information. – This could be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/196432).

Comment: Martin R thanks for your feedback. For moment my solution works ok, I don't need a new one. I just presented a little context. I want to know difference between var private(set) and let.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`let` stops you from changing the value.

`private(set) var` stops anything outside of the file from changing the value, while the class itself still has the power to modify it.

Comment: are there performance implications?